# loopings GIFs with animation package in R

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a GIF that loops with the `animation` package in R.  But for some reason, even if I set the option `loop=TRUE`, the images I make only play once and then stop.  I would like the GIF to keep playing indefinitely.  Any tips?

```
install.packages("animation")
library(animation)

saveGIF({
  for (i in 1:10) plot(runif(10), ylim = 0:1)
},loop=TRUE,interval=0.2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me. `loop=TRUE` is the default setting. Are you sure that the problem is not in your GIF viewer?

```
library(animation)

ani.options(
convert = shQuote('C:/Program Files (x86)/ImageMagick-6.8.1-Q16/convert.exe')
)

saveGIF(
{
  for (i in 1:10) plot(runif(10), ylim = 0:1)
},
movie.name = "test.gif", 
interval = 0.2, 
ani.width = 300, 
ani.height = 300,
outdir = getwd()
)
```

p.s. I'm guessing that your code works without the addition of the pointer to the `convert.exe` program since you are able to produce the .gif.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Including the `outdir` setting fixed my problem.  What was happening was that R was generating the GIF to a temp folder, opening it up with Preview (OS X), and I was saving it from there.  Apparently the step of saving the GIF from Preview instead of getting the output GIF was removing the loop behavior

Comment: Yup, +1 for this comment. Setting the outdir() solved this problem for me to (I was having an identical issue with Preview removing the loop behavior).