# Convert path not used in the R animation package

Tags: r, animation, filepath

I have started using the `animation` package today, and have installed `ImageMagick` version 6.9.1. I am working in `RStudio` in a Windows 7 64-bit environment, with `R` version 3.1.3 and `animation` version 2.3.

I am having problems trying to pass the path to `convert.exe` to `R`. I do not yet know if this code works, because I can't get the file path to be interpreted correctly. The space in the file path in `Program files` seems to be causing the issue and I can't work out how to fix the problem. I checked my path information in Windows based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6135579/1030648) and the correct path is in there.

For all examples below, this is the animation code I am trying to get to work, which is plotting three cumulative probabilities onto the same plot, using base R.

```
 saveGIF(
   {
   plot(HourlySplineModel2(Hours),type="l", col="red", xlab="Hour periods", ylab="Cumulative Prob Incubation Duration")
   lines(HourlySplineModel(Hours), col="blue")
   lines(HourlySplineModel3(Hours), col="black")
   },
 movie.name = "test.gif",
 interval = 0.2,
 ani.width = 300, 
 ani.height = 300,
 outdir = "C:/Users/files"
 )
```

Trying the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28710980/1030648) I use:

```
 path.to.convert <- paste0(shortPathName("C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16\\"), "convert.exe")
 ani.options(convert=path.to.convert)
```

and I get this error:

```
 Executing: 
 "C:\PROGRA~1\IMAGEM~1.1-Q\convert.exe" -loop 0 -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif"
 'C:\PROGRA~1\IMAGEM~1.1-Q\convert.exe" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 Output at: test.gif
[1] FALSE
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\PROGRA~1\IMAGEM~1.1-Q\convert.exe" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif"' had status 1 
2: In cmd.fun(convert) :
  '"C:\PROGRA~1\IMAGEM~1.1-Q\convert.exe" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif"' execution failed with error code 1
```

The associated path values are (from `ani.options()`):

```
 $outdir
 [1] "C:/Users/files"

 $convert
 [1] "C:\\PROGRA~1\\IMAGEM~1.1-Q\\convert.exe"
```

I have also tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17585972/1030648):

```
 ani.options(convert = shQuote("C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe"))
```

and I get this error output in the console instead:

```
 Executing: 
 "\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe\"" -loop 0 -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif"
 The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
 an error occurred in the conversion... see Notes in ?im.convert
 [1] FALSE
 Warning messages:
 1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe\"" --version' had status 1 
 2: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe\"" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif"' had status 1 
 3: In cmd.fun(convert) :
 '"\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe\"" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif"' execution failed with error code 1
 4: running command '"\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe\"" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif"' had status 127
```

The associated path values are (from `ani.options()`):

```
 $outdir
 [1] "C:/Users/files"

 $convert
 [1] "\"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe\""
```

Thinking I might be getting too complicated, I also tried (with single quote, and also with double quote instead just in case:

```
 ani.options(convert = 'C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe')
```

Which recreates the same, earlier error output:

```
 Executing: 
 "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe" -loop 0 -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif"
 'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
 Output at: test.gif
 [1] FALSE
 Warning messages:
 1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif"' had status 1 
 2: In cmd.fun(convert) :
 '"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe" -loop 0  -delay 20 Rplot1.png "test.gif"' execution failed with error code 1
```

and the directories created are:

```
 $outdir
 [1] "C:/Users/files"

 $convert
 [1] "C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16/convert.exe"
```